# Linq Query nested List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List with each Foo containing a List,

I would like to filter the items in List based on a condition in the DateTime list.  For example I would like to get all Foo items that have duplicate datetimes within the embedded list.

I've tried a number of things, but I think my logic is slightly flawed within what I am aiming to achieve.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you put the code that you have tried so far, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Does a Foo have a list of DateTime or what do you mean by "in the DateTime list"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

Random r = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    foos.Add(new Foo { Bar = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(r.Next(0, 365)) });
}

IList<Foo> filteredFoos = foos.Where(f1 => foos.Count(f2 => f2.Bar == f1.Bar) > 1).ToList();
```

Where Foo looks like:

```
class Foo
{
    public DateTime Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you (even though it's hard to figure out what you have / need, as Andrew already stated):

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
    {
        this.Dates = new List<DateTime>(dates);
    }

    public IList<DateTime> Dates { get; private set; }

    public static IEnumerable<Foo> FindFoos(IList<Foo> source)
    {
        return from f in source
               where f.Dates.Distinct().Count() < f.Dates.Count
               select f;
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** It's not efficient at all. Using different data structures or a more sophisticated algorithm will speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var duplicateDateFoos = foos.Where(foo => foo.DateTimes.GroupBy(d => d).Any(dateGroup => dateGroup.Count() > 1));
```

This will, for each foo, group the list of DateTimes by their DateTime values. If there, for a specific foo, exists a grouping with more than one item - i.e. at least two entries in this foo's DateTimes has the same value - then this foo will be added to the duplicateDateFoos list.